# Open graphics device within sourced script?

Tags: r, graphics, output

I am using R, and I am sourcing another script within one master script. Within the sourced script, I have code that looks like the following:

```
pdf("Figs/bar_gni.pdf")
m1table$Country1 <- reorder(m1table$Country, m1table$GNIpc2005)
ggplot(m1table, aes(y=GNIpc2005, fill=Level)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Country1), data=m1table, stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("GNI Per Capita, 2005") +
  xlab("Country") +
  ylab("GNI per capita, Atlas method (current US$)")
dev.off()
```

The important part, if I'm correct, is that I'm opening a pdf graphics device, making a plot, and then closing the device.

When I run the source script itself (by opening the script), this all works just fine. However, when I source it, none of my graphs are outputted. It seems to create the files, but it just creates blank files.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot graphics are only plotted when their objects are printed.

On the command line this happens when you type it in. Just as typing `sqrt(2)` prints the answer because the command line automatically calls `print`, doing `ggplot(.)+geom_line(.)` calls `print` and that makes the plot.

IN a script, the results aren't auto-printed.

So wrap all your `ggplot` calls with `print(ggplot(whatever))`.

This is an R FAQ. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Comment: Ah, didn't know what a lattice graphic was so I just overlooked that. Let me try that.

Comment: On the plus side it means you can store plots in objects (`foo=ggplot(...)`) and then do `print(foo)` later to display them. In your case, the sourced script could be a function that returns a plottable object that the master script can plot at some time.

Comment: I think that's a great idea, and your suggestion worked. Thanks so much!